# Can't assign to function call/curve not showing

Tags: python

I'm currently writing a Python Processing code where I need to animate a curve with equations defined as X(t) and Y(t). However, I keep getting the "can't assign to function curve" error. I tried writing the equations without the X(t) and Y(t) (which fixed the error), but no line is shown animating on my screen- it's just blank. Do I need to fix my window size? I'm new to coding and can't figure out for the life of me what's wrong. Any help is much appreciated (code shown below)

```
from coordsys import *

class Point:
    def __init__(self, theX, theY):
        self.x = theX
        self.y = theY
# constructor with initializations
                      
# functions to calculate x and y
def calculateX(t):
    X(t) = t - 2
    return t

def calculateY(t):
    Y(t) = (t - 2)**2
    return 0

def setup():
    global t, ptlist
    
    size(600, 600)
    
    colorMode(RGB, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    stroke(1.0, 1.0, 0.4)
    fill(0.4, 0.4, 1.0)
    
    t = 0.0
    ptlist = []
# initialize time step, point list
    
def draw():
    global t, ptlist
    
# set up coordinate frame, line weight, background
    coordinateFrame(-1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    borderWeight(3)
    background(0.25, 0.0, 0.1)
    
    xCoordinate = calculateX(t)
    yCoordinate = calculateY(t)
    
    myPoint = Point(xCoordinate, yCoordinate)
    
    ptlist.append(myPoint)
    print(ptlist)
    
    t += 0.1
    
    if t > 2.0:
        noLoop()
```

Comment: Don't post images.  Post your actual code, and post enough of it that we can run it here.

Comment: Please post your code as formatted text instead of images.

Comment: `coordsys` from where did you import this library?